# I have to directly set remote.origin.url

Tags: git

I work on Ubuntu. Every time when I trying to clone repo I have to set `remote.origin.url` directly.

On Windows I just need to git clone "repository-name" and I haven't to set `remote.origin.url` every time to clone the right repo.

What should I do to clone repo on my Ubuntu like on Windows?

On that moment, my `git config remote.origin.url` look like this :

```
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/username/repo1.git
```

and when I try to `git clone https://github.com/username/repo2.git` it's cloning repo1, not repo2.

Comment: Can you try git remote set-url origin new.git.url/here

Comment: I found solution. I should to unset global config of remote.origin.url. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution by [@anton-karatkevich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11176513/anton-karatkevich)

Solution according to the same author **@anton-karatkevich** :

> "I should to unset global config of `remote.origin.url`."